# Is there any authentic Chan Buddhist lineage operating in the West/Europe?

Tags: mahayana, chinese-buddhism

I mean Chinese Chan Buddhism, not Japanese Zen or Korean Seon. If not, what is the best course of action if one wants to become a monk in Mahayana Buddhism, but not in Theravada and not in Vajrayana? I am especially fond of Master Xuyun, are any of his disciples still around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only two Ch'an lines active in the West that I know of, the first one founded by [Hsuan Hua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hsuan_Hua). Its [headquarters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_Ten_Thousand_Buddhas) are in California. It has branch temples, for the West mainly in the US, [listed on this page](http://www.cttbusa.org/cttb/relatedlinks&branches.asp).

The second is the Western Chan Fellowship, who actually list Xuyun in their [lineage](https://www.westernchanfellowship.org/about-the-western-chan-fellowship/lineage-of-the-teachers/lineage-chart/), and has [branches in the US and Europe](https://www.westernchanfellowship.org/contacts/overseas-contacts/).

Comment: this is a good answer: 'authentic' is loaded unless we're talking about lineage

Comment: The answer was great indeed. As for authentic, loaded or not, there are authentic and inauthentic practitioners and lineages, Xuyun mentioned the degeneracy of dharma and decreasing human potentialities several times in his dharma talks. I would like to practice in a serious environment, there are far too many abusive teachers around. Btw, does anyone know if the current teacher of Western Chan Fellowships is 'controversy free'? https://www.westernchanfellowship.org/about-the-western-chan-fellowship/teachers-of-the-western-chan-fellowship/#c1843

Answer (score 1):

There’s an Obaku lineage in NJ.  It’s not purely Chinese, but definitely more “mainland” than it is Japan.

Of course, unless you’re looking tie back into your family’s culture, does the nationality really matter?  Sitting is sitting.  Your legs hurt the same if you’re speaking Chinese, Japanese, or English.